# Exclude directories in find that don't contain a specific filename?

Tags: unix, find

Let's say I have a directory containing a number of subdirectories, each with a number of files in them. I wish to check which of these directories do not contain a specific file. For example, if these are my directories:

```
dir/A:
    foo
    bar
dir/B:
    bar
dir/C:
    foo
dir/D:
dir/E:
    foo
    bar
```

If I wanted to list all directories not containing `foo`, I would get:

```
dir/B
dir/D
```

Is it possible to do this with unix `find`, or do I need to use some alternate tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a good solution after a bit more research:

`find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/foo' \; -print`

Where you replace `foo` with whatever file you're looking for.

This will print out a list of all directories that don't contain whatever file you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the current folder `./ ` that is present in the output?, since if I need to copy these sub-directories to another directory, the presence of  `./` would be detrimental

Comment: @rambalachandran Well it is an very late answer to that, but yes there is. Simply replace the `-print` with this: `-printf '%P\n'` :)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
comm -3 <(find -type d) <(find -name foo -printf '%h\n')
```

- get all directories
- get only directories that contain `foo`
- compare, printing only the difference

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create a simply 1 liner script in the current directory (or somewhere in your path). Let's name it `check.sh`:

```
cd "$1" && [[ ! -f "$2" ]] && pwd
```

2 - Give execute permission to above script:

```
chmod +x ./check.sh
```

3 - Finally use this find command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./check.sh '{}' foo \;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, here's a one-liner that should work:

```
ls | xargs -I dir ls dir/foo > /dev/null
```

The trick is that `ls */foo` will silently pass over non-matching directories (directories that don't contain 'foo'), so using `xargs` will force it to give us output to **stderr** on directories that don't contain foo. Then it's just a matter of throwing away **stdout** to just see what we're looking for.